# Shell theme selection is disabled in Tweaks tool in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I'm having a problem that I can't change my theme. I've downloaded a theme and I unzipped it and put it in `usr/share/themes`. But now the shell theme selection in Tweaks tool is disabled and I can't add my theme.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install and activate a [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

It lets you activate GNOME shell themes even from directories (`~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes`) in your home.

Comment: ok  I downloaded it and unziped it what shall i do next ?

Comment: @MolhamMohamed Place the `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` folder in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Then log out and log in.